# Easy way to define wire output multiplexers in Verilog

Tags: verilog

For the wire type in Verilog, I know that I can define a multiplexer as follows

```
wire a;

assign a = select ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;
```

And for reg's, I can do it as follows

```
reg a;
always @ (select)
begin
    case(select)
    1'b0: a = 1'b0;
    1'b1: a = 1'b1;
    endcase
end
```

Now my question arises - it's so easy to describe complex multiplexers using regs/always blocks/procedural statements. It seems so tedious to do the same with wires. **What if I wanted to describe a very complex multiplexer driving a wire? Would my select? line be huge?**

Comment: AlfoJang, you should be declaring your variables as reg or wire depending how you assign to them, not choosing how to assign to them based on how they are declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `case` and declare the signal as a `reg`. The distinction between `wire` and `reg` in Verilog is rather artificial anyway -- there's really no functional difference between them, just some (mostly historical) syntax rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
assign a = somefunction(select);
function somefunction(input sel);
begin
  case(sel)
  1'b0: a = 1'b0;
  1'b1: a = 1'b1;
  endcase
end
endfunction
```

The only complication is *every* input to your block of logic has to be an input your function.

Using the variable form, you can use `@*` and not worry about it.